# Border-image transparency for CSS

Tags: css

I have an image, that I created with border CSS. However, on chrome, it doesn't fill up the center of the div with the appropriate color and it's transparent.

[image: This is the image]

When I put a background to white, it interferes with the transparency of the borders, which is why I couldn't put it in. Is there another way around this (cross browser compatible of course)?

```
#post-wrap {
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0px 40px 70px 40px;
    width: 850px;
    border-width: 96px 17px 15px 36px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png) 96 17 15 36 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png) 96 17 15 36 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png) 96 17 15 36 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png)     96 17 15 36 repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Don't use `>` for formatting code; indent each line with four spaces instead.

Comment: Putting a second `div` inside the first, and making that `background-color: white` comes to mind

Comment: "_However, on chrome, it doesn't fill up the center of the div with the appropriate color and it's transparent._" No, it does. Your `border-image` is white in the center block, thus - it fills the content of the box. You must make that part of your image transparent.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle that highlights this issue a little better than the screenshot above does: http://jsfiddle.net/Vf3qj/

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add "fill" for it to include the background.

```
border-image: url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png)     96 17 15 36 fill repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than using border image, I think I would set this image as the background of my div and used padding to position the text inside...

```
#post-wrap {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 40px 70px 40px;
    background: transparent url(http://www.nicxtay.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/postbackground.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```